# SEO and Trademark

Tags: seo, symbols

if I quote a trademark in my site and add the ® (trademark symbol) near the word I want to be searchable or the expression I want the search engines to find, would it difficult the search engines to find?
Lets say that I'd like to write a blog and quote Batman. Should I always use the ® (trademark symbol) near Batman? Like Batman®.
Would Google or another search engine read it simply as Batman ?
And what about Batman® Mobile ? Would they read as is or would the search engines ignore the trademark symbol?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an [SEO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/can-we-ask-seo-questions-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it either next to the word or a space after. Google appears to ignore it, and a way to test this in case you are worried, is type in any registered trademark word in "...." quotes, and then type it in "....®" and you will see that Google will show just the word only. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is a trademark or service mark?

1. A [trademark](https://www.setindiabiz.com/trademark-registration.html) is generally a word, phrase, symbol, or design, or a combination thereof, that identifies and distinguishes the source of the goods of one party from those of others.
2. A service mark is the same as a trademark, except that it identifies and distinguishes the sourceof a service rather than goods. Throughout this booklet, the terms “trademark” and “mark” refer to both trademarks and service marks.

Do trademarks, copyrights, and patents protect the same things?

1. No. Trademarkscopyrights, and patents protect different types of intellectual property.
2. A trademark typically protects brand names and logos used on goods and services.
3. A copyright protects an original artistic or literary work. A patent protects an invention.
4. For example, if you invent a new kind of vacuum cleaner, you would apply for a patent to protect the invention itself.
5. You would apply to register a trademark to protect the brand name of the vacuum cleaner.
6. you might register a copyright for the TV commercial that you use to market the product.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCiZ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Search engines does not give any weightage to trademark symbol in SERP. Search engines will omits the special characters from Title and Meta atgs.

You just keep using the trademark symbol with brand name, and try to keep it in bold and header tags. This will help you to give signal to search engines regarding the trademark. And also link the official social profiles with search engines.

Thanks